# Advanced custom field doesn't show the select box as disabled in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am using Advanced Custom Fields PRO 5.0.7
One field which is select box has disabled value like

```
"disabled": 1
```

When I add a new module which has disabled field, it couldn't act like disabled unless I update the form and reload it again. 
Is there any other option to set it as disabled?

Comment: if there is same key it will conflict, give different key and try again

Comment: no, it is unique. @HardikRaval thanks, btw.